# Upload CSV stream from Ruby to S3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv, heroku, amazon-s3

I am dealing with potentially huge CSV files which I want to export from my Rails app, and since it runs on Heroku, my idea was to stream these CSV files directly to S3 when generating them.

Now, I have an issue, in that `Aws::S3` expects a file in order to be able to perform an upload, while in my Rails app I would like to do something like:

```
S3.bucket('my-bucket').object('my-csv') << %w(this is one line)
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Did you look at S3 Multipart gem? https://github.com/maxgillett/s3_multipart I dont think direct file saving to s3 is possible until they are not generated.

Comment: I am building the CSV on the fly, in a background job, I don't upload it via some kind of interface.

Comment: @AndreiHorak did you find the solution?

Comment: @Tonja unfortunately not, and I didn't have time to dig much into it. Hope you'll run into better luck!

Comment: @linkyndy I have the same requirement. Did you get any solution on this?

Comment: @logesh Unfortunately, not.

Answer (score 17):

You can use s3 multipart upload that allows upload by splitting large objects to multiple chunks.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/mpuoverview.html

Multipart upload requires more complex coding but aws-sdk-ruby V3 supports `upload_stream` method which seems to execute multipart upload internally and it's very easy to use. Maybe exact solution for this use case.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-ruby/v3/api/Aws/S3/Object.html#upload_stream-instance_method

```rb
client = Aws::S3::Client.new(
  region: 'ap-northeast-1',
  credentials: your_credential
)

obj = Aws::S3::Object.new('your-bucket-here', 'path-to-output', client: client)

require "csv"
obj.upload_stream do |write_stream|
  [
    %w(this is first line),
    %w(this is second line),
    %w(this is third line),
  ].each do |line|
    write_stream << line.to_csv
  end
end
```

```
this,is,first,line
this,is,second,line
this,is,third,line
```

The argument to the `upload_stream` block can usually be used as an IO object, which allows you to chain and wrap CSV generation as you would for a file or other IO object:

```rb
obj.upload_stream do |write_stream|
  CSV(write_stream) do |csv|
    [
      %w(this is first line),
      %w(this is second line),
      %w(this is third line),
    ].each do |line|
      csv << line
    end
  end
end
```

Or for example, you could compress the CSV while you generate and upload it, using a tempfile to reduce memory footprint:

```rb
obj.upload_stream(tempfile: true) do |write_stream|
  # When uploading compressed data, use binmode to avoid an encoding error.
  write_stream.binmode

  Zlib::GzipWriter.wrap(write_stream) do |gzw|
    CSV(gzw) do |csv|
      [
        %w(this is first line),
        %w(this is second line),
        %w(this is third line),
      ].each do |line|
        csv << line
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Edited: In the compressed example code, you have to add `binmode` to fix the following error:

```
Aws::S3::MultipartUploadError: multipart upload failed: "\x8D" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8
```

Comment: Thanks Mitsutoshi! This is just what I was looking for. I also added examples of the block-based CSV generator and IO wrappers, which could also be used to compress via gzip before uploading to S3

Comment: Do you know how I can set content type when I upload file with upload_stream?

Comment: @Kazuki You can pass arguments like this. `s3obj.upload_stream(acl: 'private',  content_type: 'text/csv; charset=UTF-8') do |stream| ...` s3obj is supposed to be like this `s3obj = Aws::S3::Object.new('your-bucket-name', path, client: client)`

Answer (score 4):

```
s3 = Aws::S3::Resource.new(region:'us-west-2')
obj = s3.bucket.object("#{FOLDER_NAME}/#{file_name}.csv")
file_csv = CSV.generate do |csv|
    csv << ActionLog.column_names
    ActionLog.all.each do |action_log|
      csv << action_log.attributes.values
    end
  end
  obj.put body: file_csv
```

`file_csv = CSV.generate` is to create a string of CSV data in Ruby. After creating this string of CSV, we put to S3 using bucket, with the path

```
#{FOLDER_NAME}/#{file_name}.csv
```

In my code, I export all the data to an `ActionLog` model.

Comment: Surrounding your answer with an explanation would seriously improve it.

Comment: Thanks! I has updated my Answer, but My english is not good, sorry :(

Comment: I tried really hard to improve your grammar and spelling. But I admit that my approach may be insufficient. I couldn't infer all meaning.

Comment: This doesn't answer my question. I specifically refer to "streams". Check my reply on the other answer as well.

Comment: Note that `ActionLog.all.each` will load all `ActionLog`s into RAM. You should do `ActionLog.find_each`.

Answer (score 2):

I would have a look at http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSRubySDK/latest/AWS/S3/S3Object.html#write-instance_method as that might be what you're looking for.

**EDIT**
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UploadObjSingleOpRuby.html might be more relevant as the first link points to ruby aws-sdk v1

```
require 'aws-sdk'

s3 = Aws::S3::Resource.new(region:'us-west-2')
obj = s3.bucket('bucket-name').object('key')

# string data
obj.put(body: 'Hello World!')

# IO object
File.open('source', 'rb') do |file|
  obj.put(body: file)
end
```

Comment: That's still an already built file. I want to progressively upload chunks of a file.